# How to keep dynamicly added controls ater postback? Javascript, JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, hidden

Good Morning all.  I have an issue that I am trying to solve but I am stuck, partially due to me not having a full understanding of JSP/ Java platform, and not having a full understanding of what/ how to implement my code in the right way.  I do have an ASP background, so I am a bit familiar with some concepts.

The issue I am running into is:  I am trying to populate a dynamic label and text box to appear on a webpage (JSP).  I have successfully been able to populate the textboxes with a piece of JavaScript code, however, when I submit the form (on Postback) my dynamic controls are gone but all of my static controls are still present.  I need to find a way to keep my information in the dynamic control on submit as well.  The form does not submit when I have errors but when the form finish rendering all information and dynamic text are all lost.

My Solution:  I have decided to use hidden fields to hold this information but I am unable to fire off the hidden fields after form submit:  Please have a look below

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm(){
        var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
        if (x==null || x=="" && document.getElementById('two').value==1){
            alert("EMPTY");
            document.getElementById('text').style.display = "block";
            return false;
        }else{
            document.myform.submit();
        }
    }

    function display(el) {
        if (el.value == "two") {
            document.getElementById('text').style.display = "block";
        }else {
            document.getElementById('text').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('dynbox').value = '';
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
    <label >First Name</label> <input type="text"/>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="one" value="one" onchange="display(this);"/>Eligible
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="two" value="two" onchange="display(this);"/>Not Eligible
    </div>
        <div id="text" class="glassy" name="mytext" style="display:none;">Other: <input type="text" id="dynbox"/>
    </div>
    <div> 
        <input type="hidden" name="mytext" value="${mytext}" />
        <br></br>
        <input type="submit" onclick="validateForm()" value="Submit"/>
    </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

What I am trying to do is select the "Not Eligible" option and type some text in the text box 'mytext' then press submit.  Once I press submit, and if the First Name textbox is not filled in, then I want to trigger my hidden textbox so that I won't loose my information in my dynamically created textbox.

I hope this makes sense.  I am not sure of how to do in JSP.  Can someone give guidance on how to get my expected results?  Keeping dynamic controls after Postback?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use Ajax to submit the form rather than regular HTML submit.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know AJAX well enough to tackle that yet!  But will look at some documentation on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing first: don't let the names `Java` and `Java-Script` confuse you. They have (almost) nothing in common. What you are using here is Java-Script only (no Java, no JSP anywhere).

Anyway, I think it is the condition in your `validateForm()` function that does not work.
I tested it a little bit and it works with these changes:

**your form**

```
 <form name="myForm" action="test.html" method="get"  onsubmit="return validateForm();">
        <label >First Name</label> <input type="text" id="firstName"/>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="one" value="one" onchange="display(this);"/>Eligible
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="two" value="two" onchange="display(this);"/>Not Eligible
        </div>
        <div id="text" class="glassy" name="mytext" style="display:none;">Other: <input type="text" id="dynbox"/>
        </div>
        <div> 
            <input type="hidden" name="mytext" value="${mytext}" />
            <br></br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </div>
    </form>
```

I simply changed the first input and gave it an ID (since I couldn't find the id 'fname' anywhere), so we can access it with JavaScript.

The next thing is your submit button. You had an additional `onclick="validateForm()";` there – which indeed calls the validateForm function but does not listen to the returned value (it executes the function.. nothing more). So the `onsubmit="return validateForm()"` is enough.

**your validate function**

```
       function validateForm() {
            var x = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
            if ((x == null || x == "")) {
                alert("EMPTY");
                //  document.getElementById('text').style.display = "block";  
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

`x` can now be retrieved by the element's id (which I find easier).. Anyway, the if condition was one of the problems. In your form you set the value of your radio button 'two' to `two`. But in the if condition you ask if could be `1`... which (in my understanding) should never happen. I just removed it to show you that your function works like this. If you want to check the state of the second radio button, you can test it like this:

```
if(document.getElementById('two').checked == true)
```

or even better

```
if(document.getElementById('two').checked)
```

one last thing: in your else statement, you can simply return `true` instead of calling `submit`.. because here:

```
 onsubmit="return validateForm();"
```

you ask your `validateForm()` function to give you either `true` and then submit or `false` and then stop submitting.

Oh, one last thing (it'S the last, promise): Java and Java-Script handle all `&&` and `||` in the order: first ´x==null´ would be tested and then `x=="" && document.getElementById('two').value==1` would be evaluated together (&& has a stronger binding than ||).. Just for your information :)

Comment: Thanks so much.  I will try ALL of your suggestions and let you know what comes of it!

Comment: Thanks, I got this to work!  You have answered my question.  Thanks so much.  I basically have to be very careful with the id's when I am calling the js functions.

Comment: Great, I am glad you got it working. I know what you mean, working with all those ids and classes can get pretty confusing :)